# JS Как правильно добавлять и удалять из DOM элемент

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Не получается удалить по событию Onclick

```html
<button onclick="elemAdd()">Добавить элемент</button>
<button onclick="elemDelete()">Удалить элемент</button>
<script>
  //        Добавление элемента
  function elemAdd() {
      newdiv = document.createElement('div')
      newdiv.classList.add('NewDiv');
      document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
      newdiv.style.border = 'solid 4px green';
      newdiv.style.width = '100px';
      newdiv.style.height = '100px';
      newdiv.style.background = 'grey';
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Это новый обьект. вставленный в ДОМ";
    }
    //Удаление

  function elemDelete() {
    this.removeChild(newdiv);
  }
</script>
```

Что не так?
п.с Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<button onclick="elemAdd()">Добавить элемент</button>
<button onclick="elemDelete()">Удалить элемент</button>
<script>
  var newdiv;
  // Добавление элемента
  function elemAdd() {
      newdiv = document.createElement('div')
      newdiv.classList.add('NewDiv');
      document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
      newdiv.style.border = 'solid 4px green';
      newdiv.style.width = '100px';
      newdiv.style.height = '100px';
      newdiv.style.background = 'grey';
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Это новый обьект. вставленный в ДОМ";
    }

  // Удаление
  function elemDelete() {
    newdiv.parentNode.removeChild(newdiv);
  }
 </script>
```

Для нескольких блоков

```html
<button onclick="elemAdd()">Добавить элемент</button>
<button onclick="elemDelete()">Удалить элемент</button>
<script>
  var divs = [];
  // Добавление элемента
  function elemAdd() {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div')
      newdiv.classList.add('NewDiv');
      document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
      newdiv.style.border = 'solid 4px green';
      newdiv.style.width = '100px';
      newdiv.style.height = '100px';
      newdiv.style.background = 'grey';
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Это новый обьект. вставленный в ДОМ";
      divs.push(newdiv);
    }
  
  // Удаление
  function elemDelete() {
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
      divs[i].parentNode.removeChild(divs[i]);
  }
 </script>
```